# Xamarin.iOS - autosize image in storyboard to fill screen

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm not sure if this question is asked before, but I couldn't find the answer to my specific problem.

I have a Xamarin.iOS storyboard (in Visual Studio for Windows) and I want the image in this storyboard to fill the screen for every screen. I have no idea how to do that, so I first simply tried to set four constraints (top, bottom, left, right) to 0 and see what happens. This didn't work:

[image]

[image]

It seems a bit too red and I'm guessing this is not good.

Does anyone know how to make sure this image is filling the screen for all screens? (thus full screen)

UPDATE: request since something is wrong (see comments).

The image does not appear correctly on the screen (a bit set to the right, so the splash screen is not centered). This is my current input:

[image]

The image is set to ScaleToFill.

Answer (score 0):

You could click the **More options...** top right of storyboard, and set left/right/top/bottom distance for each edge.

[image]

Then select **Presets** for **All Sides**

[image]

Then it will fill all sizes of screen.

=================================Update==================================

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works with only one problem: the image is not filled to the upper section of the screen, while it is filled to the lower, right and left section. This can be seen in the final result. Do you know how to solve this? I've set all sides to 0, but there is still a white open space at the top of the screen.

Comment: When I set the contraints the exact same way you did, then the image is larger than the screen (looking at the visualizer)

Comment: @GaneshGebhard How about only setting `-20` for the top constraints and others is `0`?

Comment: I did that as well, but then the image (set as splash screen) is not centered, but rather a bit to the right of the screen.

Comment: I think I now what is wrong: the code maintains the aspect ratio of the image. How can I let it ignore this aspect ratio? The image is set to ScaleToFill.

Comment: @GaneshGebhard You can go to properties of `UIImageView` to set that in storyboard.

Comment: It is already set to ScaleToFill, what other option should I use?

Comment: @GaneshGebhard You could update the screenshot of `ImageView`(designer) in question, I will check that.

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot of the designer, hopefully you can find the error.

Comment: @GaneshGebhard Hi, now we will use Xcode to edit StoryBorad now, you could have a look at my updated answer.